# How do I declare backslash constant character in C#?

Tags: c#, char, constants, backslash

How do I declare backslash constant character in C#?

```
char Character_BACKSLASH = '\';
```

Thank you!

Rune

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`Lexical structure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure)

> A character that follows a backslash character (\) in a character must
> be one of the following characters: **', ", \, 0, a, b, f, n, r, t, u,
> U, x, v**. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

So you just need to use;

```
char Character_BACKSLASH = '\\';
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
char Character_BACKSLASH = '\\';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your backslash literal:

```
const char BACKSLASH = '\\';
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the built-in value:

```
Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
```